# Initialise first n members only of struct or array

Tags: c++, initialization, clang, aggregate-initialization

I'm using the clang compiler (c++ 11 I think) that comes with RAD studio 10.2. By mistake I discovered today that the first n members of a struct or array can be assigned using the usual curly brackets e.g.

```
int a[500]={1};
struct {int a,b,c;} st={2,3};
```

The above compiles and works fine but I've never come across this or seen it used before and I can find no mention of it online (maybe I'm searching using the wrong type of wording). Is this c++ documented?

Comment: I think the first assignment you did with {1} will not assign 1 to all 500 elements but it assigns 1 to first element only.

Comment: Check this out https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization

Comment: If you do not want this to happen, look at the compiler flags `-Wmissing-field-initializers` or (if you want to be strict about it) `-Werror=missing-field-initializers`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization),

(emphasis mine)

> **If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members** `and bases (since C++17)` or initializer list is completely empty, **the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are initialized** `by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` **by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types** and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates).

That means, for `int a[500]={1};`, the 1st element is initialized to `1` and the remaining 499 elements of the array are value-initialized to `0`. For `struct {int a,b,c;} st={2,3};`, the member `a` is initialized to `2` and `b` is initialized to `3`, the last member `c` is value-initialized to `0` too.

Answer (score 6):

> I've never come across this or seen it used before and I can find no mention of it online (maybe I'm searching using the wrong type of wording). Is this c++ documented?

Yes, this is documented. This syntax is called list initialisation - and more specifically since the types are aggregates: This is aggregate initialisation.

> Initialise first n members only of struct or array

It is not possible to only initialise some members / elements. If you list initialise class object or array, then all of it will be initialised. The members / elements which lack an initialiser will be value initialised.

If you wanted to do that, then what you can do instead is default initialise the class object or array, and then initialise the sub objects selectively afterwards.